# Best way to pair a DC-DC boost converter and a MOSFET to compensate for MOSFET voltage drop

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter

I'm building a PWM fan controller, and would like to use a DC-DC Boost converter to compensate the voltage drop across the MOSFET.

What I would like to get an opinion on is if it's more efficient to boost the voltage before the MOSFET, or after.

I think it would be better to use the boost converter after the MOSFET since it will automatically adapt to any variation on the MOSFET output caused by operational temperature changes.

I'm not in any way an engineer, and don't have enough knowledge to make calculations, I'm still learning that part...

For prototyping, I'm using an IRF830, which will be replaced by logic level MOSFETs on my final product. The DC-DC boost converter is a MT3608 2A, but I'm planning to include something like it in the final project.

Thank you in advance for any inputs on this.

Edit: Insert a basic schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAonZr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How much of a voltage drop are you expecting to see across the MOSFET when it's on, and why do you think it's significant enough to justify the extra complication of the boost converter?

Comment: *.. compensate the voltage drop across the MOSFET.* If you have so much voltage drop across your MOSFET that you need to do something about is then my only conclusion is that **you're using the MOSFET in the wrong way**. I have designed a PWM controller with a MOSFET and there the voltage drop across the MOSFET (when switched on) is so small that we can neglect it. If you have more than 0.1 V drop you are using the MOSFET wrong.

Comment: Hi. I'm prototyping this with an IRF830, which will be replaced by a logic level MOSFET on the final assembly.  This MOSFET is dropping 0.7v, and I haven't chosen the final MOSFETs yet. It's also a recycled part from an old PCB that I recycled. I might not need the DC-DC boost in the final assembly, but for testing, and learning, what would you recommend? Wiring the DC-DC boost converter before or after a component that causes a voltage drop?

Comment: What is your gate drive voltage?

Comment: 5v from an Arduino Uno R3.

Comment: Honestly, forget about it. Just live with the 0.7V drop until you can get the proper part (which is cheap and easily available).

Comment: Thank you. Still, to help me understand this, if I were to set up something like this, it would be better to have the DC-DC boost after the MOSFET?

Comment: What do you mean after the FET? Do you want to power down the Boost converter? Maybe update the question with a schematic?

Comment: Schematic added. Would this be better than having the DC-DC boost converter before the MOSFET in a circuit, and increasing it's output voltage to compensate a voltage drop?

Comment: Most DC converters won't like being powered by PWM (remember, they are actively trying to output a steady voltage, usually have capacitance on the input/output, etc). Some of them have Enable pins to turn on or off, making the FET unnecessary for ON/OFF (and still probably unhappy being driven by PWM). Essentially what you have is an XY problem and are trying to solve it in the "wrong" way.

Comment: "The DC-DC boost converter is a MT3608 2A, but **I'm planning to include something like it in the final project**." - Why?

Comment: Hi Bruce. It's explained in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, I would put it after. (after all the voltage dropping components). If the voltage drop is variable, you will have a variable voltage output if you put it before. HTH.

Comment: That's a bad idea. The reasons are explained in the other answer and in the comments.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea to re-boost voltage in his application. But to answer his question "boost the voltage before the MOSFET, or after?", generaly, I would say "after". I think my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using a PWM switch on the input of a boost converter will not generate the result you are looking for.  As you reduce the average voltage using the PWM duty cycle, the boost converter will increase the boost ratio and draw more current while the mosfet is on.  Remember there is also an input bypass capacitor on the input of the boost converter.

You need to put the PWM control on the output of the boost converter, switching the low side is ok.  The IRF830 is a very poor choice for the mosfet, with 1.5 ohms Rds-on.  It will also not be fully saturated at Vgs = 5V, you need a logic level mosfet.  Since you are only switching 12V @ 2A max, take a look at something like the IPP055N03L.  There a lots of good candidates, look for logic level gate and low Rds-on.  The IPP055N03L  will have a Rdson of around 0.005 ohms at Vgs = 5V.  That resistance is going to be significantly lower than the resistance of the connectors and wire leading to the fan and can be ignored from a design perspective.

I assume you are running this from a 12V power supply, in which case you dont need the boost regulator anyway.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f21oXJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hello. The MOSFET will not be driven by PWM, the fans will get the PWM signal from an Atmega, since the PWM fans I have do not turn off with a 0 PWM signal, so I will use a logic level MOSFET as a switch. Sorry if my description induced you to think this. Also, I'm just using the current listed parts to learn how to do this, and to test code using an Arduino. It will not be used in the final assembly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating and testing this some more, it is better to use a DC-DC boost circuit right "before" the load in the circuit (DC motor, fan, etc).

My initial test circuit was assembled using a 12v 2A wall wart, from an old wireless router, that only outputs 11.4v. the MOSFET, Arduino and the circuit are dropping 0.1v, and the voltage drops another 0.1v when I set the PWM fan at full speed, having only 11.2v powering the fan.

Using the DC-DC boost I was able to get the most "bang for my buck", by having a stable 12v/11.9v output, which in the PWM fan I'm using (Corsair ML120 pro), seems to make a big difference, especially in it's "maglev" system.

Thank you everyone for your inputs, since they directed me to research information having an idea of what to search.